# array type 'Ship [10]' is not assignable - when using structs and arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make the Battleship game where a player has 10 ships. So I have created a struct `Ship` and an array consisting of 10 ships `Ship playerShips[10]`.

Now I wanted to populate my array with 10 ships, so I created a function `addAllShips()` which would return a new array of 10 ships and assign it to `playerShips[10]`. But I am getting this error:

```
main.c:34:17: error: array type 'Ship [10]' is not assignable
    playerShips = addAllShips()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Here is my `Ship` struct

```
typedef struct {
  SDL_Rect rect;
  bool isPlaced;
} Ship;
```

Here in `main()` I'm trying to populate my `playerShips[10]` array.

```
int main()
{
    Ship playerShips[10];

    playerShips = addAllShips()
}
```

And here is my `addAllShips()` function.

```
Ship * addAllShips()
{
    Ship ships[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ships[i].rect.x = 123;
        ships[i].rect.y = 456;
        ships[i].rect.w = 789;
        ships[i].rect.h = 987;
        ships[i].isPlaced = true;
    }

    return ships;
}
```

Now I would expect my `playerShips[10]` array to contain 10 `Ship` structs.

Comment: You cannot return arrays by value in C, so this code can never work. `addAllShips` also returns a dangling pointer (a pointer to an array that goes out of scope)

Comment: Your website does not work anymore Martin. Also, you cannot return arrays in C, but rather you can reference them by memory, and change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return and assign arrays.

Instead of that, you should pass the array to initialize as argument (it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element) and have the function initialize using the passed information.

```
int main()
{
    Ship playerShips[10];

    addAllShips(playerShips);
}

void addAllShips(Ship *ships)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ships[i].rect.x = 123;
        ships[i].rect.y = 456;
        ships[i].rect.w = 789;
        ships[i].rect.h = 987;
        ships[i].isPlaced = true;
    }

}
```